# Bad array shape in python

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I am trying to implement SVM for a dataset I found online.The features_test,features_train,labels_test,labels_train are python lists of tuples.I did the below to convert it into numpy arrays.But clf.fit is giving me the below error.

```
File "ebola.py", line 47, in <module>
clf.fit(features_train_numpy,labels_train_numpy)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 151, in fit
y = self._validate_targets(y)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 514, in _validate_targets
y_ = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 551, in column_or_1d
raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))
ValueError: bad input shape (2923, 9)
```

Code is as below

```
features_train_numpy = np.asarray(features_train)
labels_train_numpy= np.asarray(labels_train)
features_test_numpy = np.asarray(features_test)
labels_test_numpy= np.asarray(labels_test)
from sklearn.svm import SVC
temp = 100
clf=SVC(C=temp,kernel="rbf")
clf.fit(features_train_numpy,labels_train_numpy)`
```

Comment: and what is the shape of each array? Through `print XXX.shape`?

Comment: This code is giving me the below error
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "ebola.py", line 58, in <module>
    print np.ndarray.shape(features_train_numpy)
    TypeError: 'getset_descriptor' object is not callable
The code is this 
    features_train_numpy = np.asarray(features_train)
    labels_train_numpy= np.asarray(labels_train)
    features_test_numpy = np.asarray(features_test)
    labels_test_numpy= np.asarray(labels_test)
    print np.ndarray.shape(features_train_numpy)

Comment: Sorry for my style of commenting , Firstly i am new here and second  , I gave 4 spaces for the cpdes and errors in the comment but it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Even from the error itself it is easy to notice that your labels matrix is two-dimensional, while it should be 1D vector. It should contain on i'th position - label of i'th example. In your case it looks like each sample has 9 labels, which is not supported by sklearn SVM.